# Javascript Node.contains() returning true and false when checking if element is child of parent

Tags: javascript, parent-child, parent

I am trying to restrict the navigation on my web application to a specific element while cycling through elements using the ''tab'' key. I check if the element I just ''tabbed'' to is a child of this specific element, and if not I reset the focus on the parent element to restart the cycle.

I have tried using Node.contains as well as .parentNode, but when I console.log the operation both return true and then false when I cycle through the elements one by one using said key.

```
@Listen('keydown', { target: 'document' })
  keydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.key === 'Tab') {
      if (document.activeElement.parentNode != document.getElementById(this.targetId))
      {
        document.getElementById(this.targetId).focus();
      }
  }
```

Here is my html test code, I should be able to cycle through everything in the div, and not access the last 2 elements (I removed some code so that it's easier to get the idea):

```
<div id="targetId">
        <input>Etiam mi leo</input>
        <input>Etiam mi leo</input>
        <input>Etiam mi leo</input>
        <input>Etiam mi leo</input>
</div>
<input>Etiam mi leo</input>
<input>Etiam mi leo</input>
```

I am trying to figure out if I am using this correctly, and if yes, what could cause such a behavior?

Comment: I would strong recommend doing this using the `tabIndex` property instead of rolling your own tab handling, and having all tabIndexed elements listen for `focus`. More work, but accessibility is a real thing, unfortunately. Also on a JS note, you want `!==` (and `===`) unless you _absolutely_ know why you need type coercion at the language level.

Comment: What framework/library are you using? `</input>` is not valid HTML.

Comment: I'm using a custom library we have made in-house at my place of work.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you for your answer and your comment on the !== and === operators. I have looked into tabIndex and it does seem to accomplish the task I want to get done. However how would one be able to *temporarily* restrict access to all elements outside of a certain div? Would I not need to assign a tabIndex of -1 to all other elements every time I change the highlighted element?

Comment: The real question is why you're effectively "turning off" tabbing through your content: as web content, this should not ever happen. That tab button should always work.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm building a ''guided tour'', so I don't want people to cycle through elements of the page that are greyed out in the background. For example, I'm highlighting a part of a list, i don't want the user to be able to tab into elements of the list that aren't highlighted.

Comment: That's what the `disabled` attribute is for? But it also sounds a little like you shouldn't be using the tab button here at all, and instead have left/right or previous/next buttons on your page that people can click (or tab to, because now you have normal accessible HTML content) instead of hijacking how tab navigation works. Whether they press "tab" or press "enter" shouldn't make a different to your content, but it makes a _considerable_ difference to whether or not you're "violating" how web pages work =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I think we are getting away from the point of the question here. I do have previous and next buttons to navigate through the guided tour, what I am doing is for the sake of accessibility, so that people with text to speech softwares are able to tab through the elements without the software reading elements that aren't part of the tour.